# Exception when checking if an issue field becomes "In Progress" with workflow

Tags: javascript, workflow, youtrack, youtrack-api

My issue fields have a `State` and an option called `In Progress`

[image]

So I wrote a Youtrack Workflow that launches a http post to my discord channel when an issue *becomes* "In Progress".

Here is the JavaScript code for that:

```
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var http = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/http');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  // TODO: give the rule a human-readable title
  title: 'Open-discord-channel',
  guard: function(ctx) {
    return ctx.issue.fields.becomes(ctx.State, ctx.State.InProgress);
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    var connection = new http.Connection('https://discordapp.com');
    connection.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var response = connection.postSync('/api/webhooks/123/1DJucC8-vdZR-xxx', [], issue.description);
    if (response && response.code === 200) {
        issue.addComment(response.response);
    }

    // TODO: specify what to do when a change is applied to an issue
  },
  requirements: {
    // TODO: add requirements
  }
});
```

When activating this workflow this exception gets thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "InProgress" from undefined (open-discord-channel/open-discord-channel#16)
             org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4198)
            org.mozilla.javascript.gen.open_discord_channel_open_discord_channel_2052._c_anonymous_1(open-discord-channel/open-discord-channel:16)
```

It tells me `Cannot read property "InProgress"` but in fact `return ctx.issue.fields.becomes(ctx.State, ctx.State.InProgress);` the value `InProgress` was suggested by the embedded Youtrack Workflow editor.

Can anybody tell me how I can access the real "In Progress" value to make this code running?

### EDIT

tried this
`return ctx.issue.fields.becomes(ctx.State.name, "In Progress");`

Still gave me an exception

```
Processing issue COOPR-85:
TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from undefined (open-discord-channel/open-discord-channel#16)
             org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4198)
            org.mozilla.javascript.gen.open_discord_channel_open_discord_channel_2076._c_anonymous_1(open-discord-channel/open-discord-channel:16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `ctx.issue.fields.becomes(ctx.State, ctx.State.InProgress)` syntax, add a definition for the 'In Progress' state to the *requirements* section:

```js
requirements: {
    State: {
        type: entities.State.fieldType,
        InProgress: {
            name: 'In Progress'
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to avoid the `Cannot read property "name" from undefined` error, check the State field for null values:

```js
return ctx.issue.fields.State && ctx.issue.fields.becomes(ctx.State.name, "In Progress");
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so far I just found out in the last trys. It's kinda hard for me to understand those requirements. The official documentation is not clear enough why they are needed for every Field I want to use.

Comment: You are welcome! I believe that the [Requirements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/requirements.html) article may be also helpful.